# How to get hte name of my project with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get the name of my project in my database using doctrine. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PublicBundle:Projet');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->innerJoin('p.descriptions', 'd')
                    ->getQuery();

$products = $query->getResult();

foreach ($products as &$produit) {
    print($produit->getDescriptions()->getNom());
}
```

My project is in an entity and all the text is in an other:

The project:

```
<?php

namespace PublicBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Projet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pt_projet");
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetDepot")
 */
class Projet
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    //ID du projet
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjetInt", mappedBy="projet", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $descriptions;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_img", type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    //Nom du fichier de l'image du projet
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_technologie_utilisee", type="text", length=200)
     */
    //Text qui liste tout les technologies utilisées pour le projet
    protected $technologie;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_annee", type="integer", length=4)
     */
    //Année de réalisation du projet
    protected $annee;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="projets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pro_type", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    //Clef étrangère du type de projet
    //Le type de projet ne correspond pas à la catégore. Il peu être Unity, flash, image, vidéo, etc. Il permet de savoir quelle page charger pour pouvoir intégrer le projet dans le portfolio.
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_fichier", type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    //Nom du fichier du projet
    private $fichier;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_largeur", type="integer")
     */
    //Largeur du projet
    protected $largeur;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_hauteur", type="integer")
     */
    //Hauteur du projet
    protected $hauteur;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categorie", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    //La ou les catégories du projet
    private $categories;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->descriptions=new ArrayCollection();
        $this->categories=new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set technologie
     *
     * @param string $technologie
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setTechnologie($technologie)
    {
        $this->technologie = $technologie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get technologie
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTechnologie()
    {
        return $this->technologie;
    }

    /**
     * Set annee
     *
     * @param integer $annee
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setAnnee($annee)
    {
        $this->annee = $annee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get annee
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAnnee()
    {
        return $this->annee;
    }

    /**
     * Set fichier
     *
     * @param string $fichier
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setFichier($fichier)
    {
        $this->fichier = $fichier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fichier
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFichier()
    {
        return $this->fichier;
    }

    /**
     * Set largeur
     *
     * @param integer $largeur
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setLargeur($largeur)
    {
        $this->largeur = $largeur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get largeur
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getLargeur()
    {
        return $this->largeur;
    }

    /**
     * Set hauteur
     *
     * @param integer $hauteur
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setHauteur($hauteur)
    {
        $this->hauteur = $hauteur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get hauteur
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getHauteur()
    {
        return $this->hauteur;
    }

    /**
     * Add descriptions
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function addDescription(\PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions)
    {
        $this->descriptions[] = $descriptions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove descriptions
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions
     */
    public function removeDescription(\PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions)
    {
        $this->descriptions->removeElement($descriptions);
    }

    /**
     * Get descriptions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getDescriptions()
    {
        return $this->descriptions;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Type $type
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setType(\PublicBundle\Entity\Type $type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return \PublicBundle\Entity\Type 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Add categories
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function addCategory(\PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $categories;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove categories
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories
     */
    public function removeCategory(\PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
    }

    /**
     * Get categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }
}
```

Here is the entity with all the text of my project:

```
<?php

namespace PublicBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Projet Inter
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pt_projet_int");
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetIntDepot")
 */
class ProjetInt
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    //ID du projet
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Projet", inversedBy="descriptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pro_id_CE", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    //Clef étrangère du projet associé
    protected $projet;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_lang", type="string", length=2)
    */
    //Langue de la carégorie
    protected $langue;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_nom", type="string", length=30)
     */
    //Nom du produit
    protected $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_description_cours", type="text",length=100)
     */
    //Description cours du projet
    protected $descriptionCours;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_description_complete", type="text",length=250)
     */
    //Description complete du projet
    protected $descriptionComplete;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_roles", type="string",length=60)
     */
    //Roles joués dans la création du projet
    protected $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_aptitudes_developpees", type="string",length=200)
     */
    //Aptitudes développées lors du projet
    protected $aptitudesDeveloppees;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set langue
     *
     * @param string $langue
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setLangue($langue)
    {
        $this->langue = $langue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get langue
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLangue()
    {
        return $this->langue;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set descriptionCours
     *
     * @param string $descriptionCours
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setDescriptionCours($descriptionCours)
    {
        $this->descriptionCours = $descriptionCours;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descriptionCours
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescriptionCours()
    {
        return $this->descriptionCours;
    }

    /**
     * Set descriptionComplete
     *
     * @param string $descriptionComplete
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setDescriptionComplete($descriptionComplete)
    {
        $this->descriptionComplete = $descriptionComplete;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descriptionComplete
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescriptionComplete()
    {
        return $this->descriptionComplete;
    }

    /**
     * Set roles
     *
     * @param string $roles
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get roles
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * Set aptitudesDeveloppees
     *
     * @param string $aptitudesDeveloppees
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setAptitudesDeveloppees($aptitudesDeveloppees)
    {
        $this->aptitudesDeveloppees = $aptitudesDeveloppees;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get aptitudesDeveloppees
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAptitudesDeveloppees()
    {
        return $this->aptitudesDeveloppees;
    }

    /**
     * Set projetId
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Projet $projetId
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setProjetId(\PublicBundle\Entity\Projet $projetId)
    {
        $this->projetId = $projetId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get projetId
     *
     * @return \PublicBundle\Entity\Projet 
     */
    public function getProjetId()
    {
        return $this->projetId;
    }

    /**
     * Set projet
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Projet $projet
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setProjet(\PublicBundle\Entity\Projet $projet)
    {
        $this->projet = $projet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get projet
     *
     * @return \PublicBundle\Entity\Projet 
     */
    public function getProjet()
    {
        return $this->projet;
    }
}
```

When I try to get the name ('nom') it tells me:

Attempted to call method "getNom" on class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I had forgotten to put the index of the description. Here it is:

```
foreach ($products as &$produit) {
    print($produit->getDescriptions()[0]->getNom());
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `$produit->getDescriptions()->first();`. I'm not sure what calling that does if there are no `$description` objects in your result, but the array dereferencing you are doing above will trigger an `undefined offset` notice, followed promptly by a `non-object` fatal error, so you should probably handle that. `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` has a `count()` method which should help you mitigate for that.